# best way to do not redundant query?

Tags: php

I created the Rest API that are based on the MVC model. So far everything is working well but I want to find a clever way for the future when I'm 20 or 30 models that will communicate with the database. In particular, in every model functions should I write a query like this:

```
if($stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT first_name FROM table WHERE id = ?"))
{
        $id = 86;
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->bind_result($res);   
        $stmt->fetch();

        echo "My name is => " . $res;

        $stmt->close();
 }
```

which becomes annoying. How can I do something like CodeIgniter? I do not want to use external libraries or frameworks because I'm trying to learn how to build a base alone. Now I understand that this question probably does not fit fully into the community standards but I hope someone will understand that it is still a technical question.

Comment: If you're using an MVC pattern, you shouldn't be echoing anything in the Model, that's the responsibility of the View

Comment: But as all of your models are likely to need a find method that will return a  record by its id, create a baseModel class containing that method, and have each model extend that base

Comment: @MarkBaker I know this, in each model I take the data from the db, return it and so the result will be printed by the controller resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do so you can create a class that contains a class that can accept parameter to communicate with db as the way you want to do.

For example: 
you can create a method like `function getAll($table)` which will return all rows of a the `$table`. Then you won't need to write same table fetching code again and again. You can just call `getAll("users");` which will return all rows of your `users` table, or `getAll('products`);` which will return all rows of your 'product' table. I assume that the code inside those helper method won't be difficult for you. 
Here is how you can make your given code less redundant.

```
function findFromTable($table, $id){
  if($stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT first_name FROM $table WHERE id = ?"))
  {
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->bind_result($res);   
        $stmt->fetch();

        echo "My name is => " . $res;

        $stmt->close();
  }
}
```

Hope that will get you out or redundancy.

Comment: Nope. Each models already retrieve the data from db, I'm looking for something that make simple the query as `$this->db->select()->orderBy...` instead of the code shown above

Comment: If you want the exact same methods as codeigniter providing than you can just use codeigniter. Moreover, you can also have look into the code of codeigniter, Its open.

Comment: I should use a database layer?